# Lost access to phpmyadmin after deploying django

Tags: django, nginx, nginx-config

I used to be able to access to phpmyadmin via `http://myip/phpmyadmin`, but after deploying my django site on the same server using uwsgi, the link above will result in 404. I guess I don't have the config for the path in my `urls.py`. What do I need to do to have my access back to phpmyadmin?

Comment: What's your hosting provider? Do you have another access to the server, maybe ssh?

Comment: So I think that your problem is about nginx, please post your nginx config (Please use pastebin)

Comment: How have you installed phpMyAdmin — did you use your distribution package manager or did you download it yourself? Which web server are you using?

Comment: @Isaac Bennetch, I installed Vesta CP, then I followed this article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04 to deploy my django project on it. While I managed to get my project up and running on my IP, I couldn't figure out how to access to phpmyadmin. My current solution right now is moving my db to another server and remote connect to it. Note that I don't know anything about configuration Nginx. I don't even know what nginx is. I just followed the article

Answer (score 0):

If you have lost your access to the server you need to contact your hosting provider

Comment: No, I mean `http://myip` will now give me access to the site I made with Django, but `http://myip/phpmyadmin` doesn't work because I guess nginx and uwsgi disabled access to phpmyadmin. I don't really know

Answer (score 0):

You're using nginx as the web server (and as a reverse proxy to connect to your Django site). Another common webserver is Apache. This is an nginx configuration issue that should be easily sorted out.

According to the tutorial, you're taking any request for your site and directing it to the Django application. Instead, you want to take the phpMyAdmin URL and actually serve that web page instead.

If your nginx is already configured to properly handle PHP files, all you have to do is add a short location block like this (using the path to phpMyAdmin on your disk for the root portion):

```
    location /phpmyadmin {
        root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
        index index.php index.html;
    }
```

If you don't have PHP configured, you might need to add a few lines after the index, I think this is all but it will depend on your full configuration (and you have to adjust the socket path):

```
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
```

Test the configuration with `nginx -t`, restart the service, and give it a try. Make sure you report back here the full error message from the log if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you. Months after asking the question, I've learned what nginx and apache are and how they work. Back then I was just following instructions blindly.